# How to HALF_DOWN floating value like convert 4.8 to 4.5?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, floating-point, double

**For example:** I want to display ratings like 4.5 if values comes from server like 4.8. it is fine if server value is 5 and i have to display ratings 5.

***What i tried?***

I tried some native methods like

```
BigDecimal(libraryItem.ratingScore.toDouble()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toFloat()
```

and i tried this also

```
Math.ceil(number*2)/2;
```

But this is not working as i want

---

So simple question is How to get nearest floating number like 4.5, 3.5, 2.5 etc. if values is like 4.8, 3.6, 2.7.

Comment: You misunderstand HALF_DOWN. **It does not mean: down to half**. It means that it will generally round to the nearest value of the desried precision, but **if the value to be rounded is exactly halfway between two values**, it will always choose to round down (or, in the case of HALF_UP, to always round up, or in the case of HALF_EVEN, to the value that has the lowest *significant* bit unset).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't feel comfortable using `BigDecimal`'s way of half rounding, you may consider using the following formula:

```
double val = 4.8d;
double step = val > 0 ? -0.5d : 0.5d;
double valRounded = Math.round(2*val-step) / 2d;
```

`valRounded` will be `4.5`, as you expect.  Here is a loop showing how the values are half rounded using this formula:

```
for (double val=4d; val <= 5.1d; val=val+0.1d) {
    double step = val > 0 ? -0.5d : 0.5d;
    System.out.println(val + "->" + Math.round(2*val+step)/2d);
}

4.0->4.0
4.1->4.0
4.2->4.0
4.3->4.0
4.4->4.0
4.5->4.5
4.6->4.5
4.7->4.5
4.8->4.5
4.9->4.5
5.0->5.0
5.1->5.0
```

Comment: For −.75, this produces −1, which may not be what was desired.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I never even thought of negative numbers.  In this case, we can just negate the offset amount.

Answer (score 1):

as alternative without using Math Api is do rounding manually base on the fraction, 
bigger than half or not, then set the correct value :

```
private double roundToHalfDown(double val) {
    double half = 0.5d;
    BigDecimal bigDecimalVal = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(val));
    int intValue = bigDecimalVal.intValue();
    double fraction = bigDecimalVal.subtract(new BigDecimal(intValue)).doubleValue();
    if(val > 0) {
        val = fraction > half ? intValue + half : intValue;
    } else {    
        if(fraction == 0) {
            val = intValue;
        } else if(fraction > -half) {
            val = intValue - half;
        } else {
            val = intValue - 1;
        }   
    }
    return val;
}

roundToHalfDown(4.8);
Output : 4.5
roundToHalfDown(4.4);
Output : 4.0
```

for the simple solution you may use this formula :

```
double valRounded = Math.round((val / 0.5d) - 0.5d) / 2d;
```

here is the the output :

```
val = -3.9 ---> valRounded = -4.0
val = -3.1 ---> valRounded = -3.5
val = 4.8 ---> valRounded = 4.5
```

Comment: Converting a `double` to `int` may overflow. And this code will not handle negative values correctly.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've updated my answer, I never thought about the negative numbers

Comment: haven't, I think that formula doesn't cater for negative numbers. I tried with this val = -3.9 and got result -3.5, while it suppose to be -4.0

Comment: yes, but I see that the question is need to HALF_DOWN,
but then on the contrary that formula for negative numbers give round up result.
like val -3.1, got result -3.0.